# As an EU national, what is the easiest way to obtain a driving license?

Tags: europe, driving, automobiles, driving-licenses, dutch-residents

I am a British national with residency in the Netherlands and I was seeking the easiest route to obtain a driving license. I am already quite a seasoned driver, practising weekly on my provisional license, but as I float from country to country, I have never found the time to do the theory test in the UK and then the practical. I was wondering if there was a simple an easy way for me to simply to a practical test and then obtain a driving license (providing that I pass the practical test).

I have heard via the grapvine that one way in which Dutch citizens have been able to obtain driving licenses (at least in the past) is to travel to one of the Dutch Antilles, get a license there and convert it to a Dutch license. I was wondering if this was still possible, as I could not find an adequate answer elsewhere on the internet?

Of course, I am open to other options, so feel free to post your suggestions

Comment: This is not about travel at all. Might be on-topic in expatriates.stackexchange.com

Comment: The only way (but it's not particularly easy) is to pass all the relevant exam wherever you live. The law is quite clear on that. Obtaining a license in the Dutch Antilles, if that's currently possible at all, is at best a loophole.

Comment: I'd say the UK. No legal doubts. Just make sure you pick a part of the UK where the traffic is light and the roads not too difficult. Getting your driving license in the NL is not easy, very strict rules even compared to the UK.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, I was wondering if this was indeed a "loophole" as you call it and if someone could provide more information on it.

Comment: @Willeke But in the UK I am based in London and I am never around for long enough to deal with the waiting times to do a theory test (then a practical) and all the rest of it

Comment: London is the worst place to do your driving test in the UK, so that might harder than the Netherlands if you are located outside of the bigger cities.

Comment: You can temporarily establish residency in *any* jurisdiction whose licenses are accepted in the Netherlands for conversion, and then move back to the Netherlands and convert the license.  Answering the question requires weighing the difficulty of establishing temporary residence against the relative difficulty of getting the license there vs. in the Netherlands.  That's a very broad question, but already narrower than the one you actually asked because I've limited it to the Netherlands.  If this were on [Expatriates.SE], I'd vote to close as too broad, but it's off topic here.

Comment: I know people who go to Ukraine, get a license there and then change it for a European one.